# A ball is moving on a rough surface, what is the net work?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, friction, work

> A ball is moving on a rough surface, what is the net work?
>
> 1. Negative
> 2. Positive
> 3. Zero

From my observation, $W = \Delta (KE)$ and $KE = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$ and then $W = KE_2 - KE_1$, we can say because $v$ is smaller in $KE_2$ than $KE_1$, then work has to be negative, but I am not sure if I am right or wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Please use mathjax to format mathematical expressions. To learn more about mathjax, please read [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This is not a homework, If I want to solve my homework I go to chegg.com

Comment: It does not matter whether the question was given to you as homework or as classwork or it appeared in a test; if the question asks us to solve your problem or check your work, then it is considered to be a homework question. Read the articles which the links in my first comment take you to understand what kind of questions are considered as homework questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "rough surface" means that the surface must have a lot of friction, since that's what friction is (rough "bumps" on the molecular level).

If a surface has a lot of friction, it will always do negative work on an object since friction slows down an object, thus decreasing it's velocity and Kinetic energy (since Ke = 0.5mv^2).

Another way of looking at it is like so:  We know that friction is a negative force since it always opposes an object's motion.  The formula for Work is Force * Distance.  Since we know Force is negative and Distance is always positive (since it just has magnitude, not direction), the result (net work) is going to be negative.

Your assumption of KE_2 being smaller than KE_1 would be correct, since friction slows down the object's velocity.